# update dictionary in nested loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble updating a dictionary. i am just extracting certain fields within each key - but the output is not as expected. data, expected output and code are below. Thanks for looking, i appreciate any comments

```
categories = {'categories_a1' : [{'group': '13GH9', 'number': '1'},{'group': '17KPO', 'number': '73'}, {'group': '26BN11', 'number': '2'}, {'group': '813W', 'number': '99'}],
              'categories_a2' : [{'group': '99ITY', 'number': '12'},{'group': 'JH871', 'number': '15'}, {'group': 'OLH83', 'number': '99'}, {'group': '44RTQ', 'number': '1'}]} 

xpected= {'categories_a1' : [{'13GH9': '1'},{'17KPO':'73'}, {'26BN11':'2'}, {'813W': '99'}],
              'categories_a2' : [{'99ITY':'12'},{'JH871': '15'}, {'OLH83': '99'}, {'44RTQ':'1'}]} 
        

out={}
for k in categories.keys():
    for i in categories[k]:
        x = {k: v for k, v in zip([i['group']], [i['number']])}
    out[k] = x
out.update(out)
```

Comment: `zip([i['group']], [i['number']])` is the same as just `(i['group'], i['number'])`. Why do you think you need to iterate over a single tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first clean up some general weirdness:

```
out.update(out)
```

This line does effectively nothing and should be omitted.

```
x = {k: v for k, v in zip([i['group']], [i['number']])}
```

This makes little sense; we create lists with one element each and iterate over them in parallel. We could just as easily just use those values directly: `x = {i['group']: i['number']}`.

After swapping that in, let's consider the part that causes the actual problem:

```
for i in categories[k]:
    x = {i['group']: i['number']}
out[k] = x
```

The problem here is that you want `out[k]` to constitute a list of all of the modified dictionaries, but `x` is repeatedly being assigned *one* of those dictionaries, and the result then becomes `out[k]`. What you presumably intended to do is repeatedly append those dictionaries to a new empty list:

```
x = []
for i in categories[k]:
    x.append({i['group']: i['number']})
out[k] = x
```

However, it's clear that you're already familiar and comfortable with comprehensions, and this is an ideal place to use one:

```
out[k] = [{i['group']: i['number']} for i in categories[k]]
```

And, of course, we can extend this technique to the overall loop:

```
out = {
    k: [{i['group']: i['number']} for i in v]
    for k, v in categories.items()
}
```

---

Please carefully study the structure of this code and make sure you understand the technique. We have a source dictionary that we want to *transform* to create our output, and the rule is: the key remains unchanged, the value (which is a list) undergoes its own transformation. So we start by writing the skeleton for a dict comprehension, using `.items()` to give us key-value pairs:

```
out = {
    k: # we need to fill in something to do with `v` here
    for k, v in categories.items()
}
```

Then we figure out what we're doing with the value: each element of the list is a dictionary; the way that we process the *list* is iterative (each element of the input list tells us an element to use in the output list), but the processing of those *elements* is not (we look at exactly two hard-coded values from that dict, and make a dict from them). Given an element `i` of the list, the corresponding `dict` that we want has exactly one key-value pair, which we can compute as `{i['group']: i['number']}`. So we wrap a list comprehension around that: `[{i['group']: i['number']} for i in v]`; and we insert that into the dict comprehension skeleton, giving us the final result.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
for key, value in categories.items():
    categories[key] = [{ d["group"] : d["number"] }  for d in value]

print(categories)
```

**Output**

```
{'categories_a1': [{'13GH9': '1'}, {'17KPO': '73'}, {'26BN11': '2'}, {'813W': '99'}], 'categories_a2': [{'99ITY': '12'}, {'JH871': '15'}, {'OLH83': '99'}, {'44RTQ': '1'}]}
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time and explaining to me :) that makes a lot of sense